# javascript string isn't "string"

Tags: javascript, html

Somehow, my code does not work. I can't figure out why, I'm completely new to javascript and thought this would work, in php it's similar. if(string != "string") works in PHP, but not in javascript, in javascript the code just continues. If I do it with =! it doesn't works...

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var lastsite;

function checkSite (form){
if (document.getElementById('steam').checked  && lastsite != 'steam')
{
    $('#signaturestuff').append('<b>Style:</b> <input type="radio" name="style" value="1" id="steamstyle1" onclick="testButton();"> Style 1');
var lastsite = "steam";
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: "*`if(string != "string")` works in PHP, but not in **java***". Java or Javascript. Java!=Javascript.

Comment: "java is to javascript as ham is to hamster"

Comment: by the way variable lastsite has not assigned any sting value but you check lastsite != 'steam' which is always true.

Comment: your `lastsite` is undefined, `lastsite != 'steam'` returns true.

Comment: also, `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` is deprecated ...

Comment: Also. `$('#signaturestuff').append` requires the jQuery library, are you adding it?

Comment: Given the code you have shown, lastsite should indeed not be equal to 'steam'. What's the problem?

Comment: JavaScript(!=) doesnt do the same thing as PHP(!=) so before you attempt to convert code from one language to another, you may wish to understand the differences between them. And using $('#id') implies you have loaded jQuery which removes the need to use document.getElementById()

Comment: @therefromhere I'll edit it, it's a little fail, I know the difference...

Comment: @Rob I'm not converting, but I try to use what I learned in php.

Comment: Solved, And thank you for being so helpful to a newbie...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can compare strings with "==" in PHP and Javascript (but *not* in C, C++, C# or Java)
2. You probably *should* compare strings with Javascript compareLocale ()
3. In either case, you need to look at the value of "lastsite" in order to figure out why your comparison isn't working.  Who knows - maybe you just forgot to assign it ;)
4. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a wonderful tool, if you're not already familiar with it.
5. "[Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)" is a wonderful book, if you've not already read it.

Comment: You can compare `std::string` instances with `==` in C++.

Comment: I set the value after the append - somehow I forgot that in the code up there. I do it with: var lastsite = "steam"; Can you maybe give me some example code how it works with compareLocale()? Or how I do it?

Comment: Solved. Atleast thank you for helping.

Comment: @Bobgle `var lastsite = "steam"` will actually create a new variable with local scope (local to `checkSite`). I'm guessing you fixed it by removing the `var` keyword from that line? That way you'd be targeting the actual global variable as intended.